# How to remove TensorFlow CUDA messages? TensorFlow was installed for CPU only

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow 2.8.0 in my Windows 10 PC with CPU only. No Nvidia/CUDA hardware/software installed at all. I run a simple Python image processing project with CNN and I got bunch of no sense messages:

2022-02-23 07:31:55.511878: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-02-23 07:31:55.512119: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-02-23 07:32:16.820716: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2022-02-23 07:32:16.820934: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-02-23 07:32:16.823066: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-7OCT2M4
2022-02-23 07:32:16.823285: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-7OCT2M4
2022-02-23 07:32:16.823612: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Why I'm getting these CUDA messages? I never installed anything for CUDA. I did try the following like everyone recommended in Google:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

And still getting these messages. WHY? I really don't want to see any CUDA message because I did not install nothing for it. **This is very bad for the TensorFlow deployment team**. Why no one test this before in Windows?

I'm waiting for any suggestion to fix this TensorFlow installation issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

is the min log before the first import of tensorflow in the project? if i move the min log under the import tensorflow i will get the warnings you get

```py
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # removes tf informative messages
import tensorflow as tf  # noqa E402

print(tf.__version__)
```

Comment: sorry, this does not work at all. i did try another one and still not working:

import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
import tensorflow as tf

Comment: can you run the code attached above as a stand-alone script and tell me if the log messages still appear?